# sending .ics file as calender not as attachment using php

Tags: php, html, calendar

```
<?php
function sendIcalEvent($to_address, $startTime, $endTime, $subject, $description,  $location)
{
$from_name = 'ivan.k';
$from_address = 'ivan.k@cspl.com';
$to_name = "Ramya"; 
$domain = 'cspl.com';
//Create Email Headers
$mime_boundary = "----Meeting Booking----".MD5(TIME());
$headers = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_address.">\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ".$from_name." <".$from_address.">\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$mime_boundary\"\n";
// $headers .= "Content-type: text/calendar; method=REQUEST; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-class: urn:content-classes:calendarmessage\n";

//Create Email Body (HTML)
$message = "--$mime_boundary\r\n";
$message .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\n";
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n\n";
$message .= "<html>\n";
$message .= "<body>\n";
$message .= '<p>Dear '.$to_name.',</p>';
$message .= '<p>'.$description.'</p>';
$message .= "</body>\n";
$message .= "</html>\n";
$message .= "--$mime_boundary\r\n";

//status / url / recurid /
$ical = 'BEGIN:VCALENDAR' . "\r\n" .
'PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 10.0 MIMEDIR//EN' . "\r\n" .
'VERSION:2.0' . "\r\n" .
// 'CALSCALE:GREGORIAN' . "\r\n" .
// 'METHOD:PUBLISH' . "\r\n" .
'METHOD:REQUEST' . "\r\n" .
'BEGIN:VTIMEZONE' . "\r\n" .
'TZID:Eastern Time' . "\r\n" .
'BEGIN:STANDARD' . "\r\n" .
'DTSTART:20091101T020000' . "\r\n" .
'RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=1SU;BYMONTH=11' . "\r\n" .
'TZOFFSETFROM:-0400' . "\r\n" .
'TZOFFSETTO:-0500' . "\r\n" .
'TZNAME:EST' . "\r\n" .
'END:STANDARD' . "\r\n" .
'BEGIN:DAYLIGHT' . "\r\n" .
'DTSTART:20090301T020000' . "\r\n" .
'RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=2SU;BYMONTH=3' . "\r\n" .
'TZOFFSETFROM:-0500' . "\r\n" .
'TZOFFSETTO:-0400' . "\r\n" .
'TZNAME:EDST' . "\r\n" .
'END:DAYLIGHT' . "\r\n" .
'END:VTIMEZONE' . "\r\n" .  
'BEGIN:VEVENT' . "\r\n" .
'ORGANIZER;CN="'.$from_name.'":MAILTO:'.$from_address. "\r\n" .
'ATTENDEE;CN="'.$to_name.'";ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;RSVP=TRUE:MAILTO:'.$to_address. "\r\n" .
'LAST-MODIFIED:' . date("Ymd\TGis") . "\r\n" .
'UID:'.date("Ymd\TGis", strtotime($startTime)).rand()."@".$domain."\r\n" .
'DTSTAMP:'.date("Ymd\TGis"). "\r\n" .
'DTSTART;TZID="Eastern Time":'.date("Ymd\THis", strtotime($startTime)). "\r\n" .
'DTEND;TZID="Eastern Time":'.date("Ymd\THis", strtotime($endTime)). "\r\n" .
'TRANSP:OPAQUE'. "\r\n" .
'SEQUENCE:1'. "\r\n" .
'SUMMARY:' . $subject . "\r\n" .
'LOCATION:' . $location . "\r\n" .
'CLASS:PUBLIC'. "\r\n" .
'PRIORITY:5'. "\r\n" .
'BEGIN:VALARM' . "\r\n" .
'TRIGGER:-PT15M' . "\r\n" .
'ACTION:DISPLAY' . "\r\n" .
'DESCRIPTION:Reminder' . "\r\n" .
'END:VALARM' . "\r\n" .
'END:VEVENT'. "\r\n" .
'END:VCALENDAR'. "\r\n";
$message .= 'Content-Type: text/calendar;name="meeting.ics";method=REQUEST\n';
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n\n";
$message .= $ical;

$mailsent = mail($to_address, $subject, $message, $headers);

if($mailsent){
return true;
} else {
return false;
}
}
```

I am sending the calender request to outlook through mail using php.It have the html body content.In this the meeting.ics is going as a attachment but i want that to be send as calender request that should added automatically to the calender . if i give content type as text/calender in header the html body becomes empty.Can anyone help me with some code?
Thanks in advance

Hi got another one problem.when i set the $starttime as "2013-01-23 13:00:00" it have to get added to the calender at 01 PM on 23-01-2013 but it is added to 06:30 PM on 23-01-23.I want it to send at IST format how to do that.any sugessions?

Comment: Hmmm, looking at your code, your content-class appears to be looking a bit guilty to me.

You have sent a multipart message, and applied headers to each part, yet your content class is being applied to the entire message, and your content-class is identifying the entire message as a calendermessage.

What happens if you just omit that line?

Comment: thanks but nothing changed if i omit thet line from my code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `Content-Disposition` to you message part:

Try to change this:

```
$message .= 'Content-Type: text/calendar;name="meeting.ics";method=REQUEST\n';
```

To this:

```
$message .= 'Content-Type: text/calendar;name="meeting.ics";method=REQUEST\n';
$message .= 'Content-Disposition: attachment';
$message .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64';
```

Not sure that this work cause i didn't tested and it can behave differently on each mail client.

Comment: This behaves same as before.meeting.ics goes as an attachment but i want it to be send as an calender which should be added to the calender automatically.and one more thing my attachment goes as phising message.

Comment: Actually i just want to add the calender automatically . I don't want to send as attachment . Any suggestions?

Comment: I want to set multiday event to the calender which occurs randomly can anyone help me with some code?

Answer (score 0):

Along with the ics attachment even add another body part to your email body with following headers.

$message .= 'Content-Type: text/calendar;name="meeting.ics";method=REQUEST\n';
$message .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64';

In the content of this body part put the ics file content.

This should work!!

Comment: And yes you can ignore sending the ics attachment only the body part having ics content is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
header("Content-type:text/calendar");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$this->name.'.ics"');
```